# Change URI pattern for a single controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the below routes file:

routes.rb

```
root "pages#home"
resources :businesses
match ':id' => 'businesses#show', :via => [:get]
```

Which gives me the following routes:

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
                root GET    /                                 pages#home
          businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)             businesses#index
                     POST   /businesses(.:format)             businesses#create
        new_business GET    /businesses/new(.:format)         businesses#new
       edit_business GET    /businesses/:id/edit(.:format)    businesses#edit
            business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)         businesses#show
                     PATCH  /businesses/:id(.:format)         businesses#update
                     PUT    /businesses/:id(.:format)         businesses#update
                     DELETE /businesses/:id(.:format)         businesses#destroy
                     GET    /:id(.:format)                    businesses#show
```

I have a 'businesses' form that when completed redirects me to something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/businesses/BusinessToShow
```

How am I able to remove the controller name (businesses) from this URL redirect?

Am I able to enter a route that will change the URI pattern just for the business_path?

I specifically have the route 'match ':id' => 'businesses#show', :via => [:get]' so that a search can be done and the show action is executed without requiring the controller name, it is just the redirect that is causing issues now.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show us the code which you said redirecting after the search? or maybe the entire controller? I'm not quite sure i fully understand your question :(

Comment: I get redirected once I submit and the create action is executed. In short I would like the line 'business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)         businesses#show' in my current rake routes to read 'business GET    /:id(.:format)         businesses#show'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below routes configuration will solve your problem.

```
  resources :businesses, :except => [:show, :update, :destroy]
  resources :businesses, :path => '/', :only => [:show, :update, :destroy]
```